# Nginx Unicorn Rails VPS deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, vps, unicorn

I'm trying to run a Rails app on a DigitalOcean VPS. The server runs Nginx and Unicorn. As I'm usind Capistrano, the path of the app after pushing it to the server, is

```
/var/www/myapp/current/
```

I'm using an preconfigured droplet by DigitalOcean which seems to be configured to search for the app at the following path

```
/home/rails/
```

I've tried to change it as following:

In etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
root /var/www/
```

in home/unicorn/unicorn.conf

```
APP_PATH = "/var/www/"
working_directory APP_PATH
stderr_path APP_PATH + "/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path APP_PATH + "log/unicorn.stdout.log"
pid APP_PATH + "/tmp/pic/unicorn.pid"
```

I've followed these tutorials:
http://sirupsen.com/setting-up-unicorn-with-nginx/

These are the "official" tutorials by the hoster:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-1-click-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-10-with-digitalocean
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/an-insight-into-the-configuration-of-capistrano-1

At this point, I get the following error when I try to restart Unicorn:

```
parse_rackup_file': rackup file (service) not readable (ArgumentError)
```

Is this because the paths are wrong? Additionally, as this is my first vps deploy (capistrano, unicorn, nginx), I'm a little uncertain about some things:

Do I have more than one unicorn directory? The preconfigured vps has an unicorn folder at the home directory, right next to the rails directory which I can't use, because capistrano adds the "current" directory to the deploy. Do I need to move this unicorn directory to my /var/www/ folder for some reason?

My third and last question: I've noticed that when reading the logs of the server, I see a lot of error messages concerning missing gems. "Bundle install" doesn't help. I've found a solution for this but it doesn't seem to work properly. Is it right that I have to add the following to the top of the capistrano config file?

```
require 'rvm/capistrano'
```

I've searched for these answers for some days (over a week) now and find it extremely confusing to know where to put what in the config files, especially unicorn. I hope someone can "enlight" me before I become insane :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: My suggestion is to start from scratch. There are a lot of tutorials explaining how to go from fresh OS to deployed Rails app on a hardened VPS with Unicorn and Nginx. You'll gain a much clearer understanding of each piece of software and how they interact this way. If you're this confused now, what happens when something goes wrong *(and something **will** go wrong)*? It's a longer road to take, but if you want to manage your own server *(it's great you do!)*, it's best to not take shortcuts like installing a preconfigured box. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course I want to set up a system by myself some day but I was hoping to avoid that in the beginning. I've already learned a lot from that preconfigured system and the tutorials.

Comment: I'm having the same problems with DO's one-click image. Please let me know if you find a solution. http://askubuntu.com/questions/406702/parse-rackup-file-rackup-file-config-ru-not-readable-argumenterror-unicorn

Comment: I've spend a few more days trying to solve it but then switched to http://anynines.com. They have a similar pricing and work out of the box.